# Big trouble while linking the code to nrf5144a

Tags: c++, c, keil

While I'm trying to compile my code, I got an error:

> ".\Objects\ble_firmware_v1.axf: Error: L6405E: No .ANY selector
>   matches main.o(i.app_error_handler). "

This error appeared at linking process.

I don't know how to solve this error and why does it appear?